# Change in VsCode the foreground color for the description of a setting

Tags: material-design, themes, visual-studio-code

I am trying to modify in VSCode some of the configured foreground colors from the "Community Material Theme", as i have some serious visual problems with dark grey on dark backgrounds.

I succesfully modified the required properties for almost everything that i use except 2 elements:

1. The description of a setting in the non-json settings
2. A couple of symbols in the find tool like the regex/normal-text search type switchers (this is not that critical)

These are the settings properties i've found that are color related, but i suspect that something more general might change the description and also some non-critical symbols:

```
            "settings.dropdownForeground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.dropdownBackground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.numberInputForeground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.numberInputBackground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.textInputForeground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.textInputBackground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.headerForeground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.modifiedItemIndicator": "#ffffff",
            "settings.checkboxBackground": "#ffffff",
            "settings.checkboxForeground": "#ffffff",
```

I also tried checking out the material theme source code, but wasn't succesful in solving the problem. Thanks a lot if you are able to help!

Comment: have you ever tried any of the High Contrast Themes

Comment: @rioV8 I've just tried it thanks to your suggestion. It's better for my vision and i will use it with the current modifications i did to the non-contrast theme for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for, and it should sort both at the same time:

```
"foreground": "#ffffff"
```